# Converting from list to string to int in Python- int() function not working

Tags: python, string, list, int

I have looked and can't find anything to answer my question.
I am using `sample()` function for random numbers, but it returns a list.

I have found an easy way to convert it into a string, but the `int()` function IS NOT working to turn it into an integer. How can I fix this? Is there a way I can skip out converting to a string?

Below is the code I am using:

```
from random import sample
def ver1():
    qval = sample(range(1, 6),1)
    #This converts qval from a list to a string:
    qval_str = ''.join(map(str, qval))
    #This converts qval from a string to an integer
    int(qval_str)
    print(qval_str)

ver1()
```

Thanks in advance,
hxhu

Comment: Code works fine for me.  Well at least as well as I can tell what it is supposed to do.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output you get. "Not working" is not sufficient for us to get what you get.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, it's unclear what the issue actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not saving the result of `int()` anywhere:

```
from random import sample
def ver1():
    qval = sample(range(1, 6),1)
    # This converts qval from a list to a string:
    qval_str = ''.join(map(str, qval))
    # this creates an integer from qval
    ival=int(qval_str)
    print(qval_str)
    print(ival)

ver1()
```

`int()` returns the parsed integer as its return value - you need to save it in a variable to use it in the future

Answer (score 2):

If you want a single value (as in your example usage of `random.sample()`), just use `random.choice()` instead.